# how do I replace an unknown brand casement window?

Tags: windows

this is an old house. it has double paned casement window. some of them are foggy and need to be replaced. I dont know what brand it is. but on the casement window operator, it saids "entrygard truth". not sure if only that operator is made by entrygard or the whole window.

I just want to know if I can just go to homedepot to buy a casement window sash to replace the one I have.  I am not sure if they are all standard.

Comment: Truth is a hardware brand that a number of window makers use. How old is old? If it has double pane windows, it can't be too terribly old unless the windows were replaced in the past 40 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your window is in good shape except for the fogginess of the glass, the insulated glass unit (IGU) can be changed out by a glass installer. They will make a house visit, or you can remove the sash and they will replace the IGU in their shop.

There are shops that will "fix" the old unit by drilling a hole in the glass and evacuating the moisture out of the cavity and leave a "breather hole" in the glass. I am sure this works, and a cheap fix too, but I would not hold my breath on this type of repair.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the contractors outlet stores have replacement parts available. At least not from my experience when I tried to purchase just the double-paned sliding window section from Home Depot.

If you want to try for a window part your best chance is to contact the manufacturer directly. But be prepared for many transfers by operators to different company departments. And you'll need every number the window was tagged with.

It was simpler and faster for me to purchase a new window that was a close match. Even though there was a 6 year span between the replacement and existing windows there is no discernible difference.

Answer (score 0):

Take measurements & cross your fingers that the mounting is the same, just so you know...it won't be. Your windows are likely flanged which is a big replacement deal. Your best bet is to first find a hardware store that replaces the glass & full insulation value of the window. My last pair were $60 each (5-years ago) at Do It Best's local franchise, not fully DIY but totally worth it (takes a couple of weeks, so button up the opening).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local glass shop which deals with special orders, they *can* order replacement sealed-glass units, and can install that into the sash or refer you to someone who can.

Remember, these will occasionally get hit by baseballs, or occupants or contractors entirely by accident. And occasionallythey break in transit, or in the store, or in the factory.The manufacturers do design for repair. It may not be easy, it may not be elegant, it may not be entirely "as good as new," but it will be possible.